# jQuery: position() on created element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The following code creates a div at the bottom of the page:

```
var popup = $('<div id="popup" />')
    .appendTo('body');
```

The following code causes it to position correctly once there.

```
$('#popup')
    .position({ my: 'left top', at: 'left bottom', of: $('#someDiv') });
```

But this code causes it to appear in the DOM but not be positioned anywhere (it is not visible, but it is in the DOM).

```
var popup = $('<div id="popup" />')
    .appendTo('body')
    .position({ my: 'left top', at: 'left bottom', of: $('#someDiv') });
```

Is there a trick to being able to use jQuery position() on an item you are creating?

Cheers,
Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var popup = $('<div id="popup" />')
    .position({ my: 'left top', at: 'left bottom', of: $('#someDiv') })
    .appendTo('body');
```

Grz, Kris.